# fwprintf() "%ff" format

Tags: c

I stumbled upon the following formatting:

```
 fwprintf( file, "%ff" ,someFloat);
```

What does it mean?I know that "%ll" is "long long" [for example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) .But %ff? is it double precision float?Does such a format have any practical meaning for floats at all?

Comment: It's a float followed by an 'f'

Comment: Try it, you'll see exactly what it does.

Comment: That's clearly not [tag:c++], removed it again! If you insist I'll downvote your question.

Comment: What I see that it just prints the float value.Also I can't see how that question you @πάνταῥεῖ put above is the same? I don't scan,I write to text file and I use %ff which currently makes no apparent difference.

Comment: `"%ll"` is not a valid format string. It's just a length modifier, the conversion specifier is missing. To print out a `long long` one needs to specify: `"%lld"`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It is perfectly valid C++ code. Down-voting because you think C++ code cannot use the C standard library is ridiculous.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I didn't downvote at least ... I well know that c code can be used with c++, but this question asks for nothing c++ specific. Thus it shouldn't be tagged c++. Why else should we have separate tags for c and c++ at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%ff` format is the same as `%f` format, which stands for `float`, but the first will also write an extra f.

[credits to Oli]

What happens is that the format is treated as `%f`, while the second f as a typical character.

Example:

```
  float a = 1.2345678;
  fprintf(stdout, "%f\n", a);
  fprintf(stdout, "%ff\n", a);
```

output:

```
1.234568
1.234568f
```

So in the case of `fwprintf`, you will write at the file a redundant *f*.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
  float a = 1.23456;

  const char *testFileName = "test.txt";
  FILE *wideTestFile;
  wideTestFile = fopen(testFileName, "w");
  fwprintf( wideTestFile, L"Format ff: %ff\n" ,a);
  fwprintf( wideTestFile, L"Format f: %f\n" ,a);

  return 0;
}
```

and `test.txt` contains:

```
Format ff: 1.234560f
Format f: 1.234560
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear. +1

Comment: It's not the same, as a quick experiment would reveal.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, you are correct, I over-simplified it.

Comment: @MichaelIV in my attempt to be laconic, I didn't answer as good as I should. I suggest you have a look at my edit, since you might writing non needed `f`'s in your file.